# Error: Failed to retrieve directory listing FileZilla

Tags: laravel, ftp, ftp-client, superuser

I am trying to connect with Our application server to get access of FTP, But when I tried to access it with the help of FileZilla getting following stack trace.

I am able to see complete folder structure in CPanel. Can you help to and do let me know what are the possible issues and how can I resolve it.

```
Command:    PASS **********
Response:   230 OK. Current restricted directory is /
Command:    OPTS UTF8 ON
Response:   200 OK, UTF-8 enabled
Status: Connected
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 "/" is your current location
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 TYPE is now 8-bit binary
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (89,221,244,98,102,204)
Command:    MLSD
Response:   150 Accepted data connection
Response:   421 chdir: Permission denied
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
Error:  Connection closed by server
```

Comment: I don't have an answer but search for this `Response:   421 chdir: Permission denied` Find when  respons is `421` and `chdir:Permission` denied happens.

Comment: Please move your question to [su]. It's [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, you're trying to connect to the root folder. Change the default remote directory to a deeper folder.